# Installing Ubuntu and different drives

Tags: ubuntu-one

I am currently running a windows 7 with three drives
C windows drive 
D and E as my drives in which I store my files.

When I install new windows I format C drive so my data remains safe in D and E

Now I am sick of this svchost all RAM consumption and I tried all methods on internet to fix this svchost issue.

*I wanna know will installing Ubuntu fix this high ram usage issue ?*

Moreover most important question. If I install Ubuntu and want to remove windows basically replacing Windows with Ubuntu.
Will it erase all files in C drive only

Or will it also erase D and E also ?

Thanks this is my main issue

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu can use a lot of RAM if your computer has a lot of RAM or very little RAM if you configure it that way. This screenshot shows the RAM usage of different flavors of Ubuntu 18.04 under baseline conditions.

[image: RAM usage of different flavors of Ubuntu 18.04 under baseline conditions]

When you install Ubuntu there is a screen in the Ubuntu installer that lets you select what space on the drive to use for the Ubuntu installation, so it isn't necessary to overwrite either the existing Windows installation or whatever is stored on other drives. As you can see in the next two screenshots there are options in the Ubuntu installer that allow the user to choose the disk space that will be used for installing Ubuntu, and the Ubuntu installer will not install anything on the rest of the disk space that is not selected.

Installation type:

[image: Installation type]

Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10:

[image: Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10] 
<sup>**Allocate drive space by dragging the divider**</sup>

Answer (score 2):

As answered above, when you install Ubuntu, it will as you where and how much storage you want Ubuntu to have. You can choose whether you want C drive, D drive or E drive. If everything is saved to Drive D and E, then select C drive when installing, format how much storage you want, (If you are replacing Windows 100%, then you most likely will want to use all of your C drive, so that so space is left over, giving you another drive.), and nothing in E or D will be affected by choosing C. It will ask you before you continue if you chose the right drive, as this cannot be undone.

As for the RAM issue, Ubuntu is relatively less consuming then Windows and Mac. Linux is more for developers, but also fits into everyday users for simple functionality. Emails, the web, a few games, etc. All work great for everyone. If you are looking to dabble in the developer world, Linux is the best way to go. In my opinion, Ubuntu is the best Linux Distro, because it's multi functional. But besides that, Ubuntu really does take less ram, as it doesn't have so many powerful processes or background processes.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: My purpose is to use internet browsing and take online tutoring not video all the times and playing 1 game and other movies and videos stuff only so Linux would be better or Ubuntu

Comment: Yes, Most of Linux runs off of browser such as Java applications. Just note that just because Ubuntu/all Linux OS, is simple, you may run into a few things that can be challenging. Nothing that will be like you have to have a degree in computer science, but most answers can be found here on AskUbuntu. Before making your final choice, look over it, and make sure that switching to linux is right for you. Remember that not all Windows apps work on a linux environment, so make sure that Linux has everything you need.